# Two phase commit protocol with two sinks

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am interested in getting more details about how the two phase commit protocol works in Flink when having more than one sink. I am interested in the two cases:

1. When both sinks support 2PC
2. When one of them supports 2PC and the other not

Is it guaranteed that the distributed transaction is for all sinks or we have a different transaction per sink? In other words, if both support 2PC, one of the sinks fails, and the other is able to commit, what will happen?

Answer (score 1):

In Flink, each sink is responsible for its own state management and that includes any 2PC protocol implementation. This division is necessary as some sinks don't support 2PC at all.

When a checkpoint is triggered in Flink, 2PC sinks will start a precommit. Only if that precommit was successful, the checkpoint continues to be taken. When the checkpoint of the whole execution graph has been successfully taken (state of all operators / UDFs stored), as a last phase of the checkpoint, the sinks will perform the actual commit.

Coming back to your question: if any of the sinks fail to commit, the checkpoint will fail and with it the whole Flink application, so that it restarts with the last successfully taken checkpoint.